# Sending Large amount of data(base64 strings) to the server via ajax(post)

Tags: ajax, post, memory-leaks, base64

I have page, on which i am holding base64 representation of some images(around 1mb each ), now i am posting this data via ajax to the server(contentType is default - url-encoded). This works fine if i have one or two images to be sent, but if i have more than 2mb of request data, the server doesn't accept that, and request parameters doesn't have anything, so i increased the maxPostSize in my tomcat, and it started accepting more data as well, but i am a bit apprehensive if this would create memory issues, especially if i have lot of images ?

Also i tried changing the contentType to multipart/formdata, but it errors out, "saying the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found".

**EDIT**

I think i should elaborate more, actually requirement is something like this - User clicks on an upload link, he should be able to upload the file and then he should be able to see a thumbnail of the image on the page(all this without refreshing the page). I tried following approaches for this.

1. Reading the file using file reader, showing the thumbnail and then explicitly triggering the upload, when user clicks on save, simple but not cross browser, doesn't work in IE
2. Allowed user to upload the file send the base64 version of the image from the server and when user clicks on save, send the base64 string back to the server and convert it back to byte array and save to the db.

Now, i have a screen where all the records are by default editable, so clicking on save means, sending the image strings for all the records to the server, which will ofcourse create memory issues.

"3". Not implemented yet, but thinking of first saving the other fields(the non image fields) and then explicitly saving the images one by one(looks okay, but number of requests will be high)

Waiting for someone to suggest a 4th approach, hope i have explained enough

Comment: This is a pretty unanswerable question – how much RAM does your server have? How much is used? Why not set up a test platform that dumps out mem usage/CPU, then post different stuff at it to see what happens? If you machine has a TB of RAM, and 1000 16 core CPUs, then this probably is OK. If it's shared hosting for $5 a month, then it's probably not. Only you can answer this by testing.

Comment: As per any "upload" functionality, you will have to set a maximum allowed upload limit and stick by it. Just because you have increased the maxPostSize, this won't cause any major issues (imho) as you will be throwing away the data once it is processed (i.e. end of the request).

Answer (score -3):

Disclaimer ... Not done anything like this, but...

Why not send each image separately?   :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: ...but, like I said, I've done anything like this, but, for example the facebook photo uploader seems to do images one at a time, so perhaps that is a valid way of loading many images.  Admittedly if the goal is to load one large image, then its not a solution...